# What non-zero function is w-orthogonal to all the polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$?

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

**Background**

It is understood that a function $q$ is $w$ orthogonal to a function $p$ over $[a,b]$ if there holds:

$$ \int_{a}^{b} q(x)w(x)p(x)dx = 0$$

For example, for $w(x):=1$, $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, the underlying $w$ orthogonal polynomials are the Legendre polynomials.

**Question**

Suppose now $w := \sqrt{1-x^2}$, and $p$ is any polynomial function of degree less than or equal to $n$, what is the non-zero function $q$ that is $w$ orthogonal to any $p$?

Comment: Not answering your question but Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal w.r.t w = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality) $U_n(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible that this answer be derived? What facts do one needs to derive it?

Comment: You can get it from the formula $U_n(\cos(\theta)) = \sin((n+1)\theta)/\sin(\theta)$
with the change of variables $x = \cos(\theta)$, $0 \le \theta \le 1$.